# 2-7 hand ranking

Tags: hand

In deuce to seven hand ranking which is commonly used for draw poker if there are two players and they both have a pair then how the winner will be decided ? does the kicker card to break the tie will be of higher rank or lower rank.
eg: P1 has 3d 3s 2c Qh Ac and P2 has 3c 3h 4s As Kh

Answer (score 2):

2-7 is simply upside down poker. The hand ranking are simply reversed so what would be the worse hand in a regular hand ranking is the winner in deuce to seven. The answer to your question is that the lowest pair would be the winner.

This is true of the whole hand ranking so keep in mind that flushes and straights work against you and Aces are bad. The best hand in the game is the name of the game, 2,3,4,5,7 off suits. If you understand the five card rule for regular poker determining the winner for deuce to seven is as simple as just giving the pot to the worst hand.

And anticipating a related question suites only work against when it is a full five card flush. If both players have 23457 and neither has a five card flush it is a split pot. If you both had flushes, the lowest flush would win and the same if you both had straights, the lowest straight would win.

Where this might get confusing is that 2-7 is only one of two forms of lo-ball poker. The other form which is typically played in high low Omaha and stud games and often has a qualifier of Eight or better for low, meaning that your low must be eight or lower, has the best low hand as a five high straight. The low is determined only by the five lowest cards ***without*** flushes and straights being considered in determining the low hand.

The proper name for five card draw 2-7 is "lo-ball". Before 1987 when stud poker and Hold-em gained a legal status in California one of the few places in the US were any kind of poker was legal, five card draw was the only game allowed and "lo-ball" was the dominant game.

If you want to have some real fun at your home game instead of playing Omaha eight or better for low, play Omaha hi lo with 2-7 for low. It will get loose.

Comment: (A) To answer the OP's actual question, 3-3-A-Q-2 defeats 3-3-A-K-4 because the Q is lower than the K. (B) There is one exception to the "just poker hands reversed" rule: In 2-to-7 draw, a wheel is not a straight, but is ranked as no pair, A-5-4-3-2 high. (C) There are actually *three* ways to rank lowball hands: 2-to-7, A-to-5 (as in California lowball, Razz, Omaha, and most other H/L games), and A-to-6 (aces are low, straights and flushes are bad--this is often called "London Lowball")